# How to calculate FFT given lots of data?

Tags: python

```
def fft(self, x):
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1: return x
    even = fft(x[0::2])
    odd =  fft(x[1::2])
    T= [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
    return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + \
           [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]
```

So this is code that was given to me.  I am not sure what it does and how to fix it.  Can anyone help and explain to a learning programmer of python?  Or can anyone provide new code on how to calculate FFT?

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you have above ?

Comment: FFT is the fast-fourier-transform. To fully understand it, you probably need to take a course or two. And to fix it, you'll definitely need to understand it.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what it does.  I have a bunch of data and need to calculate FFT 1/3/5/10 second window.  I have data which is given from a bunch of participants along with how they acted 1/3/5/10 seconds before a task they needed to do.

Comment: The code above is just an implementation of the FFT - it sounds like what you need though is to understand what an FFT *does* (it's a fast implementation of a DFT).

Comment: So from my understanding, FFT calculates or an algorithm for DFT (correct me if I'm wrong).  How would I add onto the code in order to implement it onto my data for the different sec windows?

Answer (score 1):

You should use external libraries interfacing with NumPy for high-performance routines. Don't roll your own, unless you have to. [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html) has an fft routine.

Save yourself the work: Python is "batteries included".

The example they give is:

```
>>> from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> np.allclose(fft(ifft(x)), x, atol=1e-15)  # within numerical accuracy.
True
```

If you need super high-performance and have very large data (larger than memory), consider using [dask](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/fft.py).

Comment: I installed numpy/scipy and have the fft along with it.

Comment: @SLK, if I solved your question (and only if), please mark the question as closed and select the correct answer. If you have any questions using fft, feel free to comment.

Comment: I already had scipy installed.  I'm still struggling how to use it along with my code (above) to get what I want (in comments).  Trying to learn python from scratch in a short amount of time.

Comment: @SLK, read the example I gave you. You need to transform your input data to a NumPy array and then can process it like above.

Comment: After I transform my input data, would I need to make a new range for each of the sec windows (1/3/5/10) or how would I separate the windows?  Sorry for the trouble.